# Find k th index character of a binary string obtained after N iterations. In each iteration - '0' becomes '10' and '1' becomes '01'

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to identify a solution (preferably in JAVA) for the given scenario :

**Input :**

- Binary String : e.g. "1001"
- N - Number Of Iterations
- K - String index position

**After each iteration**, all the 1s become "01" and 0s become "10"
e.g.

- initial value/input --> "1001"
- after 1st iteration --> "01101001"
- after 2nd iteration --> "1001011001101001"
- ...
- ...
- after Nth iteration --> "100101011......[**Kth index value**]......00101010111.." (here our program needs to find the **Kth index value** that would be either 0 or 1)

**Output :**
value (either 0 or 1) at kth index after N iterations.

Comment: Good luck trying. Please come back to SO if you have a specific question about your written code, in what way it fails and what it should produce for a given input and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After N iterations, each original digit becomes 2<sup>N</sup> digits, so skip digits until we get close to K.

E.g. for input `"1001"`, `N=3`, `K=20`, the 1st digit becomes 8 digits, so if we skip those 8 digits twice, i.e. skip 2 original digits = 16 K's, we're at the 3nd original digit (a `0`), and have a remaining `K=4`.

We then apply an iteration on that digit, and get `0` -> `"10"`. We can now restart the operation, with input `"10"`, `N=2`, `K=4`.

Repeat until done. Solution in *O(N)*, regardless of input length or value of K.

---

Of course, you could just brute-force it, but that won't perform well at higher values, since solution is *O(L * 2<sup>N</sup>)*, with `L` being the input length.

```java
// Brute-force solution
static char solve(String input, int n, int k) {
    String s = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> c == '0' ? "10" : "01").collect(Collectors.joining());
    return s.charAt(k); // assuming k is 0-based
}
```

Compact version of solution described above:

```java
// Optimized solution
static char solve(String input, int n, int k) {
    for (; n > 0; k %= 1 << n--)
        input = input.charAt(k / (1 << n)) == '0' ? "10" : "01";
    return input.charAt(k);
}
```

Comment: thanks @Andreas for your answer..

I got the first part of your answer. But, I did not quite get the following logic/description : 

We then apply an iteration on that digit, and get 0 -> "10". We can now restart the operation, with input "10", N=2, K=4.

Repeat until done. Solution in O(N), regardless of input length or value of K.

Appreciate if you can please elaborate a bit more in detail.

Comment: @STACK_TRACKER We know that with `N=3`, each original digit expands to 8 digits, so with `K=20` we can skip the first 2 original digits, leaving the remainder `K=4`, which means that the target digit is in the expansion of that 3rd digit, and any extra original digits beyond the 3rd can be discarded. Leaving us with `input="0", N=3, K=4`. We then perform 1 iteration, expanding the digit, and get `input="10", N=2, K=4`. We can start over with that, and keep doing it, until we get to the result when `N=0`.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for your guideline .. I will go through your explanation thoroughly once again to understand it fundamentally.